# issue with stored procedure syntax using MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I most likely have a syntax issue (SQL command and error copied below) - I am using MySQL v5.1.63 on Ubuntu 11 (dbName is the name of the database, the fields mentioned are in the USERS table with the appropriate data types/lengths).  Any suggestions to troubleshoot this would be welcome.

```
use dbName;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertTest
(
IN p_ID INT(11),
IN p_UserID VARCHAR(40),
IN p_Email VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO USERS
(
ID,
UserID,
Email
)
VALUES
(
p_ID,
p_UserID,
p_Email
)
END//
DELIMITER;
```

I am getting an error when I source the file containing the statement above:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 32
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a space after `END//` and `DELIMITER;`, and also try a semicolon after the inserted values.  The corrected procedure is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertTest
(
    IN p_ID INT(11),
    IN p_UserID VARCHAR(40),
    IN p_Email VARCHAR(30)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO USERS
(
    ID,
    UserID,
    Email
)
VALUES
(
    p_ID,
    p_UserID,
    p_Email
);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```